# Открыть и прочитать файл xlsx, полученный с api, с помощью python

Tags: python, api, openpyxl

По API я получаю эксель файл в формате как на скрине. Как я могу открыть его и прочитать построчно(openpyxl). Думал он в кодировке base64, но попытка декодировать была не успешной[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужна ссылка на файл.